# Tableau : how to get a very high resolution satellite map as background?

Tags: maps, tableau-api

I have created my map in Tableau, with on it some locations (buildings) of interest. However, with the standard satellite background map, it is not really possible to see the (roofs of) buildings in full detail.

How can I get more detailed satellite maps as my background?